# (Java) Go thru array beginning at the last index

Tags: java, arrays, list

I'm currently trying to make a method in Java that takes an array of `size` digits, and is supposed to go thru the array starting at the end, adding 1 to digits <= 8, and turning 9's into 0's.

My problem is that I'm not quite sure how to start going through the array beginning at the end. I'm coming off of Python, so I'm familiar with the syntax `list[:-1]`, but I'm not sure how to apply that, or if it can be applied, to Java.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: No you can't do `list[:-1]` in `Java`.  You can use a for loop with the starting index set to the last index and de-iterate it.

Comment: Even though this is blatantly a homework/assignment question. A for loop that starts at digit index until index 0 is a good start. I.e `for(int i=digits; i>=0; i--)`

Comment: Start out simple, how would you iterate through an array in java from beginning to end? Once you solve this, it should be trivial to solve iterating from the end of an array to the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
public void someMethod(int[] arr){
    for(int i=arr.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if(arr[i] <= 8){
           arr[i]+=1;
        }else if(arr[i] ==9){
         arr[i] = 0;
    }
    }
}
```

Refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html for better undersatnding of `for loop` construct.

Answer (score 0):

Java has unfortunately no operation like `list[:-1]` so you will need to do a reversed for loop or a decremental lopp to achieve that:

```
for (int i = value; i > 0; i--) {
    System.out.println("Am decreasing over the element: " + i);
}
```

Also, please take a look at the Oracle tutorial about [for loops](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)